# Cannot establish connection to remote mongoDB server using ssh tunnel in class object

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, ssh, pymongo, digital-ocean

I have an object that initiate ssh tunnel connection to a remote mongoDB. The same script works perfectly fine in other **scraper** running in a virtual machine that write data into the MongoDB.
However, in object in my GUI application keep giving me could not establish connection to ssh gateway error, while the **scraper** with the same code works fine.

Version:

sshtunnel version  = 0.1.5

pymongo version  = 3.8.0

python version = 3.6.7

```py
    def initMongo(self):
            for attempt in range(5):
                try:
                    MONGO_HOST = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"
                    REMOTE_PORT = 22
                    MONGO_USER = "USER"
                    MONGO_PASS = "PASSWORD"
                    #I have tried this but doesnt work
                    #self.Mclient = MongoClient('mongodb://{}:{}@{}:{}/'.format(MONGO_USER,MONGO_PASS,MONGO_HOST,REMOTE_PORT),connect=False)
                    
                    sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 60.0
                    sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 60.0
                    self.remoteServer = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder((MONGO_HOST,22),
                                        ssh_username=MONGO_USER,
                                        ssh_password=MONGO_PASS,
                                        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1',27017))    
                    self.remoteServer.start()
                    self.client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1',self.remoteServer.local_bind_port) 
                    
                    self.db = self.client.db_I_want
                    return
                except Exception as e:
                    print("From Object  :{}".format(e))
                    #time.sleep(5)
                    self.initMongo()
```

```
    2019-08-25 17:54:11,266| ERROR   | Could not connect to gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx : xxx
    From Object  :Could not establish session to SSH gateway
    2019-08-25 17:54:11,290| ERROR   | Could not connect to gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx : xxx
    From Object  :Could not establish session to SSH gateway
    2019-08-25 17:54:11,311| ERROR   | Could not connect to gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx : xxx
    From Object  :Could not establish session to SSH gateway
    2019-08-25 17:54:11,336| ERROR   | Could not connect to gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx : xxx
```

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by increasing the remote database's max connection.
https://www.howtogeek.com/240809/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-ssh-connections-to-the-same-system/